# .htaccess and environment variables (do X if Env isnt)

Tags: .htaccess, environment-variables, .htpasswd

Morning,

I've got 2 entries in my .htaccess file, and I want to make them a little more dynamic.

Firstly I've got a non-www to www. redirect

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
 </IfModule>
```

However, i'd like it to function conditionally as below

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{ENV:environment} != "dev" && != "local"
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} {DOESNT_CONTAIN .staging.com}
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
 </IfModule>
```

So basically, I want the www. redirect to kick in if the env variable doesnt equal dev or local, and the domain doesnt have .staging.com in it

How would I go about sorting this?

Secondly, this is pretty much an identical issue, I've got some authentication

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /var/www/vhosts/{HTTP_HOST}/httpdocs/.htpasswd
AuthName "Protected Area"
require valid-user
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Satisfy Any
```

I would like this to only run on the same conditions as above so:
environment != "local"
environment != "dev"
url doesnt contain .staging.com

Hope some of you could shed some light onto this issue please.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the mod_rewrite part:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:environment} != "dev" && != "local"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} {DOESNT_CONTAIN .staging.com}
```

would become:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:environment} !dev 
RewriteCond %{ENV:environment} !local
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !\.staging\.com
```

For the mod_auth part, you'd need to set an env variable for the host and the dev/local:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Host .staging.com noauth=true
SetEnvIf environment dev noauth=true
SetEnvIf environment local noauth=true
```

Then add additional `Allow` statement:

```
Allow from env=noauth
```

Comment: could you explain what the line "SetEnvIfNoCase Host .staging.com noauth=true" is doing, dont quite understand it?

Comment: @OwenMelbourne See the [mod_setenvif](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif) docs. It sets an environment variable, and since the `Allow from env` only checks if an environment variable **exists**, you have to check the value of the `environment` vars using `SetEnvIf`.